# Mark numbers that exist in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a table that displays list of numbers and group of numbers from 0-9, what I'm trying to do is add an `exist` class on the numbers that exist on the list of numbers.

Please check my [sample code](https://codepen.io/gerryl1991/pen/KxdXRd?editors=0010)

the first row is result I'm trying to achieve.

Sorry, its really hard for me to explain this.

Hope you get my point.

Thanks.

```js
$('table td:first-child .rw').each(function() {
  const n = $(this).text();
  var rw = Array.from(n.toString()).map(Number);

  console.log(n);

  var $this = $(this);

  for (let r = 1; r < 6; r++) {
    if ($this.is(':nth-child(' + r + ')')) {
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $this.closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(' + (r) + ') .rw:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ') div:nth-child(' + rw[i] + ')').addClass('exist');
      }
    }
  }


});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dadce8;
  text-align: center;
}

th:first-child,
td:first-child {
  width: 50px;
}

th,
td {
  width: 180px;
}

.rw div {
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
  line-height: 24px;
}

td:first-child {
  padding-top: 3px;
}

td:first-child .rw {
  height: 24px;
}

td:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+6).rw {
  padding-top: 3px;
  height: 30px;
}

td .rw div.exist {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>numbers</th>
      <th>1st</th>
      <th>2nd</th>
      <th>3rd</th>
      <th>4th</th>
      <th>5th</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          98371
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          09827
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          18276
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          76591
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          09832
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div class="exist">9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div class="exist">8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div class="exist">3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div class="exist">7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div class="exist">1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          12312
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          89271
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          53919
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          53201
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          09832
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you tell little more? When number may be considered "exist" - when this number at the same line with numbers from the left list? (called as `numbers`)

Comment: @ya.ymer yes sir, also thanks to that edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you looking for:

```
$('table tbody tr').each(function(k, x) {
  $(this).find('td:first-child .rw').each(function(t, u) {
    const n = $(this).text().trim();
    var rw = Array.from(n.toString()).map(Number);
    var $this = $(this);

    for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
      var char = n.charAt(i);
      var d = $("table tbody tr:eq(" + k + ") td:eq(" + (i + 1) + ") div.rw:eq(" + t + ")");
      d.find("div:eq(" + char + ")").addClass("exist");
    }
  });
});
```

**demo**

```js
$('table tbody tr').each(function(k, x) {
  $(this).find('td:first-child .rw').each(function(t, u) {
    const n = $(this).text().trim();
    var rw = Array.from(n.toString()).map(Number);
    var $this = $(this);

    for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
      var char = n.charAt(i);
      var d = $("table tbody tr:eq(" + k + ") td:eq(" + (i + 1) + ") div.rw:eq(" + t + ")");
      d.find("div:eq(" + char + ")").addClass("exist");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dadce8;
  text-align: center;
}

th:first-child,
td:first-child {
  width: 50px;
}

th,
td {
  width: 180px;
}

.rw div {
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
  line-height: 24px;
}

td:first-child {
  padding-top: 3px;
}

td:first-child .rw {
  height: 24px;
}

td:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+6).rw {
  padding-top: 3px;
  height: 30px;
}

td .rw div.exist {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>numbers</th>
      <th>1st</th>
      <th>2nd</th>
      <th>3rd</th>
      <th>4th</th>
      <th>5th</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          98371
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          09827
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          18276
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          76591
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          09832
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          12312
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          89271
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          53919
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          53201
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          09832
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: sir, is there a way to use `child selector` than the `contains`?

Comment: @user123 You can use eq instead of contains, but child selector here would make no sense.

Comment: sir can you help me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52049745/connect-elements-with-same-class-using-canvas)