# Connect elements with same class using canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I'm working on a table that has sets of numbers.

every set has one number with class 'exist' because the are present on the first column.

What I'm trying to do is, to connect those numbers per column using canvas line.

I manage to get their position using `offset` but don't know how to implement it.

Hope you understand me.

Thanks.

**Sample Result**

[image: chart]

```js
$('table tbody tr').each(function(k, x) {
  $(this).find('td:first-child .rw').each(function(t, u) {
    const n = $(this).text().trim();
    var rw = Array.from(n.toString()).map(Number);
    var $this = $(this);

    for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
      var char = n.charAt(i);
      var d = $("table tbody tr:eq(" + k + ") td:eq(" + (i + 1) + ") div.rw:eq(" + t + ")");
      d.find("div:eq(" + char + ")").addClass("exist");
    }
  });
});


var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasLines');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var Point = function(x,y){
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
}

function drawLine(stPoint, endPoint,color){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(stPoint.x,stPoint.y);
  ctx.lineTo(endPoint.x,endPoint.y);
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

$('table tbody tr td:nth-child(2) .rw div.exist').each(function(i, el) {
    var ex =  $(this).offset();
  
    drawLine(new Point(ex.top,ex.left),new Point(ex.top,ex.left),'red');       

});
```

```css
table{
 width: 100%;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, td, th{
  border: 1px solid #dadce8;
  text-align: center;
} 

th:first-child, td:first-child{
  width: 50px;
}
th,td{
  width: 180px;
}
.rw div{
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
  line-height: 24px;
}
td:first-child{
  padding-top: 3px;
}
td:first-child .rw{
  height: 24px;
}
td:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+6).rw{
  padding-top: 3px;
  height: 30px;
}
td .rw div.exist{
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>numbers</th>
      <th>1st</th>
      <th>2nd</th>
      <th>3rd</th>
      <th>4th</th>
      <th>5th</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          98371
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          09827
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          18276
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          76591
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          09832
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          12312
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          89271
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          53919
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          53201
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          09832
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<canvas id="canvasLines" width="600" height="150"></canvas>
```

Comment: Might be more helpful to someone if you draw a sample drawing of the end result you were expecting; however when drawing is required (especially on top of another element) you're going to need to position both absolute with the same height and width then take relative position (x,y) of the "exists" elements (take into account their height/width for centering) from the origin container and then draw on the canvas on top of the table

Comment: @melfy sorry, I update the question.

Comment: Definitely doable, however don't think I have the time tonight:

Try dropping the tables and making each digit it's own DIV (5 columns per your numbers) with fixed width, making each column with its own canvas overlaying entire block and write a single function drawing top to bottom per column connecting the digits, then apply to each column.  Don't forget to make absolute with canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach. First get position of your div with class 'exist'. Using

```
 var cont = $('.exist');
 var pos0 = $(cont).position();
 var x0 = pos0.left,
    y0 = pos0.top,
    x1 = pos1.left,
    y1 = pos1.top;
```

Then You will have your co-ordinates. After that use following function

```
   line(x0, y0, x1, y1);


function line(x, y, x1, y1) {
    var a = $("<div class='line'>");


    a.css({
        top: y,
        left: x,
        width: Math.sqrt((x1-x)*(x1-x) + (y1 - y)*(y1 - y)),
        transform: 'rotate('+Math.atan2((y1-y),(x1-x))+'rad)'
    });
    cont.append(a);
}
```

You must loop this code in order to draw lines. Try Playing around with this. You must run this code after your canvas is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

I make some example for you here. This can do something like you want it.

Just modified it later according what you need/code/css and more. :)

HTML

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="1000">
<table class="table" style="border-collapse: collapse;border:1px solid #ccc;">
<tr>
    <th>DATA 1</th>
    <th>DATA 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
       <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div class="active">3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div class="active">7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
       <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div class="active">1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div class="active">3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
       <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div class="active">8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div class="active">5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
       <div class="rw">
          <div class="active">0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div class="active">9</div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
       <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div class="active">6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div class="active">5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
       <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div class="active">9</div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="rw">
          <div>0</div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div class="active">2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
          <div>7</div>
          <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</canvas>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var c = $("#myCanvas");
var ctx = c.get(0).getContext("2d");
var txt = c.html();
var sty = $('style').text();

var c_h = c.height();
var c_w = c.width();

var pt1 = new Array();
var pt2 = new Array(); 
var fix = 0; // dirty solution for different/gap because of padding/margin or border that have pixel (px). Not too great. but still can do its work. :D

ctx.strokeStyle="red";
$("tr",c).each(function(m,n){

    var temp = "";

    if(m !== 0){ // Skip HEADER (TH)
        if(m === 1){ // 1st row only store the offset. Not create stroke yet
            $("td",this).each(function(x,y){
                pt1.push($(".active",this).offset()); // Store the offset for each td that have active class;
            });
        }else{ // after 1st row, create stroke - from and to

            if(pt2.length){
                temp = pt2;
                pt2 = [];
            }
            else{
                temp = pt1;
                pt1 = [];
            }

            $("td",this).each(function(x,y){
                pt2.push($(".active",this).offset()); // Store the offset for each td that have active class;
            });

            for(var q=0; q<$("td",this).length; q++){
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(temp[q].left, temp[q].top+fix); // From point (active) 1
                ctx.lineTo(pt2[q].left,pt2[q].top+fix); // To point (active) 2 
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }

    }

    fix += 3; // dirty solution for different/gap because of padding/margin or border that have pixel (px). Not too great. but still can do its work. :D
});

/*
    Make table as a image type.
*/
var data = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='"+c_w+"' height='"+c_h+"'>" +
             "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
               "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='font-size:20px'>"+
               "<style type='text/css'>"+sty+"</style>" +
                    txt +
               "</div>" +
             "</foreignObject>" +
           "</svg>";
var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([data], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};
img.src = url;
```

JSFiddle working example : http://jsfiddle.net/synz/4La50o1j/